# Prime factorisation

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Is there any general method with which we can determine, how the prime factrisation of a number changes on addition of another number?
Is there any research currently going on in this area?

It would be highly appreciated if you suggest some research papers or books on the same if such methods do exist.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note the [$abc$ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) is somewhat related to what you're asking.

Comment: Some hint is the standard fact: prime factorization of $x$ and $x+1$ don't have any prime in common.

Comment: The prime decomposition of a sum bears no discernible relation to the prime decomposition of the addends.  Cf. Goldbach’s conjecture and twin prime conjecture

Comment: If we increment $a$ by an integer $b$ coprime to $a$ then $\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b) = 1,\,$ so they share no prime factors. If they are not coprime then cancelling their gcd reduces to this case.